# ViewPager using Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager which uses three Fragments, and one of the Fragments uses database operations.
So when I launch my application it takes much time to load(because of databse operation) and it crashes most of the time.
I used AsyncTask for databse operations in Fragment but still this problem is there.
Any other solutions ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you already considered these rules for AsyncTasks?

> There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:
>
> - The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done    automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
> - The task instance must be created on    the UI thread.    execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
> - Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result),       doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
> - The task can be executed only once (an exception will be thrown if a     second execution is attempted.)

from: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html